# Doubts bounded curves

Tags: calculus

I have a doubt as narrow functions, specifically especially when divided between $x$, for example $-1\leq\cos(e^x+1)\leq1$, if the above expression divided between $x$ or equivalently multiplying inequality for $1/x$ I do not know why inequality does not change, if the function $1/x$ is decreasing. Any help would be great!

Comment: I don't understand your question at all...what do you mean about "the inequality does not change"?

Comment: @Ian I mean the sense of symbol ≤ I do not know if you change to be ≥

Comment: If you apply an increasing operation to both sides of an inequality, it is preserved. If you apply a decreasing operation, it is reversed. But that is when you consider the result as a function of what's already there; for example, dividing by $x$ amounts to putting what's already there into the $y$ argument of $f(x,y)=y/x$, and $f$ is an increasing function of $y$. Thus the inequality is preserved.

Comment: @Ian Why x is an increasing function of y?

Comment: For fixed positive $x$, $f(x,y)=y/x$ is a linear function of $y$ with a positive slope...

Comment: @Ian You say that y= 1/x is positive?

Comment: Not in general, but we can restrict attention to positive values of $x $.